# GeoDjango can't find GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, geodjango, django

I'm following this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/, I installed every component necessary. But it seems like Django can't find the gdal module.

I have gdal installed by pip using the wheels in [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal). It is located in the same directory as Python 3.7: `C:\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\osgeo`

My python version is `Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32` and I installed `django` using its `pip` module.

I tried the solutions described in this questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139044/geodjango-on-windows-could-not-find-the-gdal-library-oserror-winerror-12
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197431/geodjango-cant-find-gdal-while-python-can

And including the gdal path `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\osgeo\\gdal300.dll'`

With no results.

This is the error traceback:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\base\features.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\functions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\fields.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 47, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado
```

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this by reinstalling a previous gdal version supported by django (gdal204 instead of gdal300), from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal), version 2.4.1, removing the system enviroment variables refered to gdal and including these in the django project (settings.py file):

```
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = r"C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\data\gdal"
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r"C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\data\proj"
os.environ['PATH'] = r"C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\osgeo" +";" + os.environ['PATH']
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal204.dll'
```

Comment: I hadn't ever installed gdal into my virtual environment before, but because I need a different version of it globally for other applications, this worked perfectly! thanks for posting this answer.

Comment: After testing some, I realized your PATH line is a little wrong, it needs a `;` in it like so: `os.environ['PATH'] = r"C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\osgeo" + ';' + os.environ['PATH']`.

Comment: Thanks! Finally worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Before installing Django,

1. Setup GDAL

   ```
   run 'OSGeo4W installer'
   ```

   in CMD (run as administrator), execute code by code:

   ```
   set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
   set PYTHON_ROOT=C:\Python310
   set GDAL_DATA=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\gdal
   set PROJ_LIB=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\proj
   set PATH=%PATH%;%PYTHON_ROOT%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin
   reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%PATH%"
   reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v GDAL_DATA /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%GDAL_DATA%"
   reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PROJ_LIB /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%PROJ_LIB%"
   ```
2. After installing Django App

   Added GeoDjango in 'settings.py' file as follows

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
     # [...]
     'django.contrib.gis'
    ]

   GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = "C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin\\gdal306.dll"
   ```

Now it works properly.